# Java Graphics disable xor mode

Tags: java, graphics, xor-drawing

I know that g.setXORMode(Color c) enables XOR mode drawing. But how to disable this mode after setXORMode call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`g.setPaintMode()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setPaintMode%28%29)